# Is there a way to change a global variable in a function (like as a counter) and then have it keep that value for use in another function?

Tags: python

```
For ex if a is my global var:
a = 0
def func1():
    #something happens
    a += 1
return a
(repeats 2 more times)

def func2():
      if a == 3:
    #do something
```

Would this work? I apologize if this is unclear, as I am very new to Python.

Comment: Yes it will work, as long as you put `global a` inside both functions so they know it's global.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `return` doing,
use `return` to reuse a result.

```py
a = 0
def add1(a):
   a += 1
   return a
a = add1(a)

def func1(num):
    if num == 3:
        ...

func1(a)
```